# How do I make this ISBN-verifier more efficient?

Tags: java, algorithm, isbn

I am trying to make this code more efficient. How should I go about and do it?

It is a class that is called from another one in Java. I am not the best when it comes to algorithmic efficiency so I appreciate all help I can get.

Thanks in advance.

```
public class Algorithm {
    public static boolean check(String isbn){

        if (isbn.length() == 13) {
            return check13(isbn);
        }

        else if (isbn.length() == 10) {
            return check10(isbn);
        }

        else {
            // System.out.println("Invalid length!");
            return false;
        }
    }

    private static boolean check13(String isbn) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < isbn.length(); i++) {
            int temp_val = isbn.charAt(i);
            if (i%2 == 1) {
                temp_val *= 3;
                sum += temp_val;
            }
            else {
                sum += temp_val;
            }
        }
        // System.out.println("Valid ISBN!");
        // System.out.println("Invalid ISBN!");
        return sum % 10 == 0;
    }

    private static boolean check10(String isbn) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 10; i > isbn.length(); i--) {
            sum += isbn.charAt(i) * i;

        }
        // System.out.println("Valid ISBN!");
        // System.out.println("Invalid ISBN!");
        return sum % 11 == 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "efficient"?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's more suited for [codereview.SE]

Comment: You can squeeze a few more cycles out of this code by removing the temporary variables, but before you do that you need to make it work. Neither of these methods is correct. You can't possibly have tested them properly.

Answer (score 2):

your algorithm takes as many steps as the ISBN is long, it's not going to be any more efficient than this.

Comment: Well he could eliminate the temporary variables to steal a few cycles, but when he fixes his bugs he will lose a few more, and he will certainly never be able to get it better than *O(N)*.

Comment: local variables do not directly translate to separate instructions in bytecode, let alone once hotspot is done with it; I wouldn't presume optimizing code is as simple as that.

Comment: I agree that HotSpot probably obviates it, but local variables certainly do affect the bytecode. There are extra loads and stores for the local variables.